# Missing new file in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: gnome, 13.04, nautilus, filesystem

The `New file` operation is missing in Ubuntu 13.04. How can I fix it?
[image]

I have only "New Folder".

How can I add the `New File` option again?

Comment: Related: [“Create new document” - right-click option missing in Ubuntu GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777711/create-new-document-right-click-option-missing-in-ubuntu-gnome)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is to add files in `~/Templates` directory. For example adding an empty file named `Text.txt` the `New Document` option is added.

[image]

So we can add there files with different extensions to view them into `New Document` option.

---

#### Command line:

```
cd ~/Templates
touch Text.txt
```

Comment: 17.10 is missing the "Empty Document" prompt. How do I add that?

Comment: This brings it back in “Files” (Nautilus), but not on the desktop.