# Ubuntu 14.10 Can't Create New Files from Context Menus

Tags: files, 14.10, interface

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 and I can't find the New File option anywhere. The New Folder is there, but I can't create new files except if I run the touch command in the command line.

Is there any method through which I can bring the old New File option back? I think just creating files through a touch command is really a time consuming process....(I loose at least 20-30 seconds doing this with the touch command, as opposed to 5 seconds doing it from the menu the classic way).

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your user owns the location you want to create the file.

Comment: @Rinzwind It happens everywhere - both on my desktop and on any other folder... And I am on my own account

Comment: @paxRoman Run `sudo chmod 755 /home` in Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to apply the commands discussed here:

[Missing new file in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309834/missing-new-file-in-ubuntu-13-04)

```
cd ~/Templates
touch Text.txt
```

These lines would at least give you the option to create new text files.

Another solution is to use

```
sudo nemo
```

and change the permissions to the folders individually.