# Missing new file in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome, context-menu

My question is pretty much the same like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309834/missing-new-file-in-ubuntu-13-04):

The `New file` operation is missing in context menu. How can I fix it?

The only difference is that I'm running Ubuntu 15.04. The accepted answer posted in the question above does not work for me - after creating folder `Templates` and new file inside simply nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and find `XDG_TEMPLATE_DIR`. Make sure that it looks like this:

```
XDG_TEMPLATE_DIR=$HOME/Templates
```

If not, change the value so that it looks like that.

Answer (score -1):

After you check the template setting in @David Bailey 's post.

You need to create an empty file, to say Text.txt in your $HOME/Templates folder, eg by open a terminal in that folder and

```
echo > Text.txt
```

Then you have a  "new document" in context menu.

Works for me on UBUNTU 15.04